# How to get value from UItableView for textField?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield, swift4

I have tableView on my viewController, and one textField. TableView present list of names. When I click on cell with the name, I want to get that name like textfield text.
Anybody have idea how can I do that?

Comment: paste the code. Then i directly tell you a code

Comment: func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return names.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableCell", for: indexPath)
        let names = names[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel!.text = imena
        
    return cell
        
    }
    
}

Comment: I have problem with textField text, tableview looks good

Comment: check the answer now put the break point on print. now the name of specific row is printed

Comment: @MilicaKnezevic Do not post code in comments. Please [edit] your question with all relevant details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
     let name = names[indexPath.row]
     yourTextfieldName.text = namesArray[indexPath.row]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The method didSelectRow at from tableView will give you the indexPath clicked. You are probably loading those names based on an array, you can then do array[indexPath.row]

Answer (score 1):

Add this code to your class.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    yourTextfield.text = namesArray[indexPath.row] 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When user tap of tableView cell its detected in  `didSelectRowAt` from this you can get selected cell index to find name in the array.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) { 
      let name = names[indexPath.row]  // Get selected name from array names 
      print(name)
     textField.text = name // Assign   textField text to selected name 
}
```